# What is the Center in Vector Rotate Node

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

As per [Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/vector/vector_rotate.html) the center in the `Vector Rotate` node is the **Point to rotate around**, which, I assume, means the pivot point for rotation.
However when I tried with an example, changing the center of the `Vector Rotate` node seems to merely change the rotation angle and not the pivot point.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what is happening.

The grey arrow is the vector **(0,0,1)** in object space. The red ball is the 'Center' of the *Vector Rotate* node.The green arrow is  **(0,0,1)**, *Vector Rotate*d by 90° about the axis **(0,1,0)** (into the screen), passing through 'Center'.

As 'Center' is moved along the X axis, for example, the rotated **(0,0,1)** changes length and direction as shown:

[image]

The green arrow is where you have asked the X of your plane to be directed.

Comment: Oh man, thanks for that... I was a bit confused and thought about it more like the vector like being a line which is rotated around an off-center pivot point, and keeping the same length while doing so... of course it's different.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann   Well... it _is_ a vector, but it's given an origin by the _Transform_ at the end of the chain, so it becomes a point. (At least, that's the way I'm thinking about it, until tomorrow, when my head starts spinning again)

Comment: Maybe the way to think about this is you're not rotating the vector; you're rotating the tip of the vector.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand this too well. How is the grey and green arrows both (0,0,1)? And I can't visualise the green arrow rotating 90° - is this because the centre is moving?

Comment: Hi, @Neil ! The tip of the grey arrow, the **point**  (0,0,1), (which is the vector (0,0,1) from the object origin), is being rotated by 90° anticlockwise about the Y axis passing into the screen through `center`. The 'Rotation' requested in the _Transform_ node is about the object origin, which is the moment  the vector (0,0,1) acquires an origin, and is considered a definite point in object-space, rather than just a length and a direction.

Comment: @RobinBetts It took a while, but it finally hit me. Thank you for explaining what is probably for most already well explained in your answer 

Comment: @Neil.. you're not the only one.. I don't seem to be able to tell the difference between clockwise and anticlockwise .. sorry if that added to your confusion!  8/

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the *Center* is the pivot point around which the vector is rotated. That is correct.

But in your example, you use a vector pointing from $(0,0,0)$ in the direction $(0,0,1)$.

Then you rotate it around a certain center.

If you then align a geometry on a certain axis to this rotated vector, you get the direction in which the rotated vector points.

And with it you unfortunately do not reach your goal.

---

To solve the problem you have (at least) two possibilities:

Either you rotate the positions of the individual points of your geometry and set their positions:

[image]

Or you convert the geometry into an instance and use the node `Rotate Instances`:

[image]

Comment: Although I saw immediately that Loma was using the _Vector Rotate_ wrong or misunderstood what it does, I have a hard time figuring out how the rotation it creates together with the _Align Euler to Vector_ node is calculated... for example when take a simple line to display a vectorwith two vertices 0/0/0 to 0/0/1 with origin at 0/0/0 and rotate it e.g. 45° on the Y axis around the 3D Cursor at 0.3/1.3/0.7, I get exactly what I calculate with a rotation matrix for this case. But the _Vector Rotate_ and _Align Euler to Vector_ get a different result...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann This is probably due to the fact that although `Align Euler to Vector` produces a correct rotation, this rotation is always applied at the object origin/center, no matter which center you have previously rotated the vector around.

Comment: I thought of something like that, but I just can't wrap my head around it. I thought the _Align Euler to Vector_ would still point in the same direction, only at a different origin. But they are different angles as well.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the *Align Euler to Vector* and *Vector Rotate* both output an array of 3 floats - for the former those are XYZ rotations in radians, for the latter XYZ components of the vector. There's no origin location information bundled there.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I misphrased that one, I didn't mean a stored origin information but something like the orientation would be the same, only at a different location. But it doesn't matter, I thought wrong about it anyway :D

Comment: @quellenform There's always a lot to learn from your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Quellenform's *Set Position* solution is what I would go for too, but to further clarify: normally when operating on matrices, you rotate around a point different than origin by "moving the origin" - by translating the object, rotating and translating back. For example, below I do 3 operations:

[image]

1. Rotate by $-100°$ around the 3D cursor.
2. Move the 3D cursor to $(-0.5, 0, 0)$ and rotate around this point in space.
3. Pretend I can't actually do as in p. 2., so I move the 3D cursor back to the world origin and instead use the translate-rotate-translate technique.

In geonodes:

[image]

Keep in mind you can merge 2 last *Translate* nodes, because rotation is done before translation.